# I am using sketchpy to draw an image but i got an error

Tags: python, import, module, filenotfounderror

I have written this code in python while executing i got below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DOLU RAMBABU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sketchpy\library.py", line 232, in log
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DOLU RAMBABU\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\data.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python_practice\draw.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sketchpy import library as gfg
  File "C:\Users\DOLU RAMBABU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sketchpy\library.py", line 243, in <module>
    old_data = log(1, path)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DOLU RAMBABU\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\sketchpy\library.py", line 240, in log
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DOLU RAMBABU\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\data.txt'
```

Could someone please guide me how to resolve this issue?

I am looking for solution for the above error.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example to reproduce your error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Without your code,  the only thing to go by is your traceback.  It states that ```'C:\\Users\\DOLU RAMBABU\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\data.txt'``` wasn't found.  Does that file exist?  If the file does exist, then it's something else, which as @VoNWooDSoN mentions, a Minimal reproducible example would help.

Comment: That's a pretty sly answer to the question, there, anyway.  It's very likely that OP simply doesn't know that windows needs double slashes (or to use `os.path`), but how can we know for sure without the code?

Comment: Hi voNWooDSoN, I have used below code but it seems that we are getting different error. from sketchpy import library as gfg

img = gfg.rdj()
#Initalizing the image object
img.draw()

Comment: Hi ewoox,  I have tried the below code.  from sketchpy import library as gfg

img = gfg.rdj()
#Initalizing the image object
img.draw()